# Language-independent random number generator from alpha-numeric string

Tags: java, random, parse-platform

I'm writing a program where I want to be able to generate a random integer within a set range from a seed of two 10-character alpha-numeric strings that have been randomly generated from Parse.com. (for example: "bGmwcRG6ch" and "7AdFJ4VyY3"). I also want the same number to be generated no matter what language I am running this on. This number will correspond to a predefined username stored within the program.

The part I'm having the most trouble with is I want to be able to add more usernames (increase the range of the set) in the future without changing everyone's usernames. Currently I have 200.

What I have so far (written in Java):

```
public String generateUsername(String userId, String chatId)
{
    String s = userId + chatId;

    long seed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        seed = seed + s.charAt(i);
    }

    Log.d("chatId", chatId);
    Log.d("userId", userId);
    Log.d("Seed: ", Long.toString(seed));        
}
```

Log output:

11-07 14:58:45.902 10666-10666/? D/chatId: bGmwcRG6ch

11-07 14:58:45.902 10666-10666/? D/userId: 7AdFJ4VyY3

11-07 14:58:45.902 10666-10666/? D/Seed:: 1669

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you actually want to achieve. You start by saying you want a random number, but the code you show has no randomness at all. You're also talking about a range, but all I see is a concatenation of two strings. Please clarify. Explain what you want to achieve at a higher level: why do you need those numbers?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the two strings are random generated ID's from a Parse.com server. Editing it in.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you have 2 unique strings identifying a user, and would like to transform those two strings into a unique numeric indentifier, is that right? Why? Why not use the string identifiers to identify the user? If you want a numeric ID, then you'll need to use a sequence and store the mapping table between the numeric and the string ID somewhere. Or you could use a cryptographic hash an just keep the first 8 bytes: this doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but you would be very, very, very unlucky to have a conflict, especially with only 200 values.

Comment: One thing I don't understand though, is why your code returns a String and not a long, since you want a numeric value. If what you actually want is a String, why not use the original strings in the first place (concatenated and separated by a dash, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you have written so far is complete and perfect, this logic is language independent random number generator from alpha-numeric characters.

Because this calculates the Numeric value from the ASCII values of the alpha-numeric characters, and that ASCII values are all same for any language. ASCII stands for American Standard Code for Information Interchange.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be a standard hash, either a slow but secure cryptographic hash, like [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or a faster, less secure non-crypto hash, like [FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).  In either case be sure to specify formats carefully.  For example, UTF-8 with BOM has a different byte pattern to UTF-8 without BOM.